# In what situations would a user not let the shell record his command into history?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

If I add `export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` in `.bashrc`, bash won't record any commands which have whitespace before them into history.  But I do not understand under what situations it will be useful.  Can anyone give some examples?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your commands contain passwords or other sensitive informations

Comment: But I have never see any passwords in my history and never see any commands need to contain sensitive informations.

Comment: @acgtyrant then you never entered a command with a password. The idea is if you provide a password on the commandline just put a space before the command and it won't get recorded to the `HISTFILE`

Comment: Can you tell me any commands need to contain password? I have used `sudo` very much, but I don't find any password contain in this command from history.

Comment: @acgtyrant Depends what you are doing/how you are doing it, often times you only need to provide a password if you want to automate things, e.g. to connect to a database, accessing websites, etc. and plenty more.

Comment: Oh, got it finally.

Comment: some invocations of ldapsearch also provide a means of entering a password on the command line.

Comment: mysql commands can accept the password of the user that you're connect to the database with, there are too many to list here. The point @Ulrich Dangel made is spot on. If you're typing commands with passwords, don't leave them in the history.

Comment: I'll also add that when you're and administrator you often don't want the history on because if an attacker were to get into the system you're leaving him a trail of where things are on the box and what types of commands are typically run on the box.

Comment: If you don't have any commands with sensitive information, then you're not the target audience for that feature. Not every feature in a program is used by every user. (That's one reason why programs have "feature creep": everyone uses a dozen features, but a different dozen, and wonders what all the other useless cruft is for.)

Comment: Keep in mind that command-line arguments are often visible in `ps`, or by looking in `/proc`. Some systems make the environment visible to other users as well. A mode 0700 file on a tmpfs, OTOH, doesn't have these problems.

Answer (score 26):

Another usage is for commands that you don't want to accidentally repeat, such as `rm -rf *`.  I make extensive use of history and occasionally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> accidentally when the command I've retrieved from history is not the one I was looking for.  Granted, the real solution is to always read commands carefully before executing them.  But being a bit clumbsy, I prefer to also keep particularly destructive commands out of my history as an extra precaution.

Comment: I'd add that I found it very convenient to further ignore some dangerous commands even if I forget to include a space: `HISTIGNORE=" *:rm -f*:rm -r*:*--force*"`. This prevents `rm -f` and `rm -r` from being saved into history, as well as anything that contained `--force`.

Comment: This is the/a real solution. Don't leave knives around, saying the real solution is to not poke yourself with them. As the old proverb goes “you can't un-wee in the river” — meaning don't clean the river, instead stop dumping rubbish into it.

Answer (score 6):

A former coworker of mine did this with most `cd` and `ls` commands, to record only the "useful" commands.

Comment: I almost never run nethack at work without doing this... (or top, or man...)

Comment: Actually, someone can add `export HISTCONTROL=ingoredups` in `.bashrc` to tell bash not to store duplicates so make history more clear. You can read this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-bash-history-more-efficiently-histcontrol)

Answer (score 2):

Data privacy. The moment law enforcement breaks down your door, you may not want them to find residues of

- where you wget the latest pron^Wwarez from
- what movies you recently ripped and fed to a torrent
- passwords passed via arguments to encryption/decryption programs

Seriously, it's probably the equivalent to a strict privacy setting in your browser, stopping it from recording surf history.

Answer (score 0):

If you [version control .bash_history](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/bc62528a399719a060fb6b597145b40c6c91a4ca/.bash_history) it's a useful way to mark certain commands as "special". Combined with [history-search-*](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/bc62528a399719a060fb6b597145b40c6c91a4ca/.inputrc#L1-L3), it's a way to press simply <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run `make --directory ~/dev/tilde clean` and <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run `editor ~/.bash_history`, both of which I use for maintenance of the Bash history file.